# What is the mechanism to advise that (and why) a question has been edited?

Tags: discussion

I recently edited a question [What is the difference between 'genealogy' and 'family history'?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/1424/70) that appeared at risk of closure, because I felt that it captured important issues that need to be answered. At least one other member thought the same and re-edited my effort to move it closer to a "good" question.

But how do others who have read the original question (or my hack) and then moved on, know that we are trying to rejuvenate the thread? Is there a standard procedure that I should have followed after the edit?

We are rapidly approaching the point that it will not be practicable to review previous conversations for updates each time I drop-in. How are "major" updates flagged?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edited questions go back to the "top" of the list, just as if it were a new question. Also listed under the question, next to the original author is the last person to edit it and how long ago. Clicking on the link will show a complete change log of the question with all the edits made and by who.

There is no "major" marking - each edit is treated the same.

Comment: Thanks. I was concerned that there was something I needed to do. Good to know that the "system" has it in hand.