# How do people who closed a question know it's been updated?

Tags: support

I now realize this question  (as originally posed) is a duplicate to [make-the-faq-clear-on-how-a-question-can-be-reopened](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1164/what-is-the-mechanism-to-advise-that-and-why-a-question-has-been-edited). Thank you @ColeValleyGirl. I'm not sure why it didn't show up when I googled it - I got hits on other faqs (that didn't seem pertinent) but not this one. So I am modifying this question to ask that the genealogy faq have a similar faq and refers to the meta.se faq referenced.

Answer (score 1):

[What is the mechanism to advise that (and why) a question has been edited?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1164/104) is relevant -- your edited question popped up at the top of the active list. Once somebody has proposed re-opening (and I'm not sure whether you could have done this yourself) it will show up in the list of items to review for those people with the appropriate privileges.

There's also some relevant suggestions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120372/make-the-faq-clear-on-how-a-question-can-be-reopened/152026#152026)